# Reading data separated by ';' from file

Tags: c, file, parsing

I am trying to read in data from a file that is formatted with `;`.
The data will always be of like this:

```
char[];int;int%;int
```

The `char[]` can have any number of spaces and the `%` should be disregarded when reading the data.

I am using `fscanf()` (I am allowed to use only that) for reading the data from the file.

Right now my code for that part of it is:

```
fscanf(file, "%[^;]%d%d%d", f_name, &f_id, &f_score, &f_section_num) != EOF)
```

Is there a regex for what I need? Or, how do I correct my `fscanf`?

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466894/how-to-read-through-data-in-a-file-and-pass-it-to-a-struct-c/19467418#19467418

Comment: what about something like`while(4 == fscanf(file, "%[^;];%d;%d%%;%d", ...));`

Comment: @Anand I looked at that before posting this question and even tried what they did, but I am still getting an error.

Comment: note that due to `%[^;]`, which also consumes a new line character, your program will read in a two-line input like `abc\nxyz;3;4%;5` as one line.

Comment: `fscan` does not support regex. For the syntax of the format string, what abou the documentation is unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file using `fscanf` with this format string:

```
"%[^;];%d;%d%%;%d"
```

- `%[^;]`: read up to first `;`
- `;`: ignore the `;`
- `%d`: read one integer
- `;`: ignore the `;`
- `%d`: read one second integer
- `%%`: ignore the `%`
- `;`: ignore the `;`
- `%d`: read one third integer

Do not forget to test the number of successful conversions made by `fscanf` by testing `fscanf(...) == 4`

So code will looks like:

```
FILE *f = fopen(...);
char name[64];
int i, integers[3];

while (fscanf(f, "%[^;];%d;%d%%;%d", name, &integers[0], &integers[1], &integers[2]) == 4)
{
    printf("name is %s\n", name);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("i[%d] = %d\n", i, integers[i]);
    }        
}
fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow you to read data separated by `;` from your file:

```
char msg[100];
int  a;
char b[100];
int  c;

fscanf(fptr, "%[^;];%d;%[^;];%d", msg, &a, b, &c);
printf("%s\n %d\n %d\n %d\n", msg, a, atoi(b), c);
```

Comment: This assumes, perhaps unsafely, that no component on the line will exceed 99 characters.

Comment: The third field is, I think, meant to be an integer followed by `%`, so `;25%;` or similar.  You seem to be treating it as a string, which is only partially correct — you'd have to convert the string to an integer, possibly after validating for a percent symbol at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could, alternatively, use `strtok()`. If, for example, you use a struct for each entry as follows,

```
typedef struct {
    char name[64];
    int id, score, section_num;
} entry_t;
```

the following would read each line of the file as follows.

```
char line[128] = {'\0'};
char *field = NULL;
entry_t entry;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    field = strtok(line, ";");
    if (!field || strlen(field) > sizeof(entry.name)) continue;
    strcpy(entry.name, field);
    field = strtok(NULL, ";");
    if (!field) continue;
    entry.id = atoi(field);
    field = strtok(NULL, ";%");
    if (!field) continue;
    entry.score = atoi(field);
    field = strtok(NULL, ";");
    if (!field) continue;
    entry.section_num = atoi(field);
    // Do whatever you need with the entry - e.g. print its contents
}
```

I have removed some necessary boilerplate code for brevity. See http://codepad.org/lg6BJ0hk for a full example.

You can use `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` if you need to check the results of the integer conversions.

Comment: I tried using this, but I felt it's a bit unnecessary for what I am doing right now.

Comment: @Varun.R: It is, admittedly, more long-winded. If you have a solution using `fscanf()`, just go with that I suggest. I think I will leave this answer here anyway, as an alternative.